# Can I write publications if I don't have co-authors?

Tags: publications

I'm currently studying a BSc so I'm not fully involved in academia yet. I'd still like to write some publications and have them peer-reviewed about specific subjects. 
According to [Does one need to be affiliated with a university to publish papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/does-one-need-to-be-affiliated-with-a-university-to-publish-papers), I can publish even without an affiliation, but do I need co-authors? If so, how to find any?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it definitely can be done.

If you have an idea then do a literature review of the subject and if you have a contribution that builds on the activity in one of the journals you find then publish there. Perhaps also look into doing a conference paper first. See [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18349/difference-between-conference-paper-and-journal-paper) for the difference between the two.

The best co-author for your case would probably be a professor or grad student at your university.

No, co-authors are not required. They can be useful though if you need their help/skills in the project.

In computer science, journal papers usually occur during one’s PhD. Bright Masters and Honours students usually start publishing conference papers, but journal papers are not unheard of.

Comment: Note that there are fields in which conference papers basically don’t exist.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft As far as I understand Luca is a CS guy and there many important papers are submitted to conferences.

Comment: @Alexandros: But the question has not been asked specifically about the field of computer science. So if a part of the answer is specific to this (which is fine), this should be marked. As it is written right now, this is a wrong statement – though the intended statement is correct.