# Changing PhD topic and effect on career

Tags: phd, research-topic

I'm a PhD student in my third year (4-6 is common in my country) and seriously consider abandoning my current topic. 
The new topic is in the same general field (CS related), yet in a vastly different domain and would need a quite different methods. My advisor suggested this switch, he could keep me funded in both cases, yet probably better with the new topic.

Arguments for switching are both personal interest in the new topic (it's recently trending, I was interested from the beginning, yet few positions were available) and lack of progress in the current area:

1. I could produce some publications, yet not up to my advisors expectations (should be easier with the new topic, given the impact factors of the journals my advisor suggested)
2. For the last 6-8 month I made barely any progress (lots of failed experiments)
3. I would probably have to abandon my current methods anyway due to 1./2., so half a year or so will be lost learning new methods no matter how I decide

Yet I shy away from switching, mainly due to already being quite old (combination of personal problems and a switch of my major as an undergraduate) and fearing how my C.V. would look if I did take about a year longer and had this second switch...

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Beware of the «the grass is always greener» fallacy when switching subjects. What is your precise question?

Comment: It's more about the long term effect of making such a switch. I should probably add my field (CS related) for further context. I think/hope I'm aware of the fallacy, yet I'm rather confident about the new topic being easier to publish in (remarks from advisor about desired venues and their impact factors).

Comment: *"the new topic being easier to publish in"* The notion that there are high-impact journals that are rather easy to publish in seems somewhat contradictory. In my experience, literally *every* venue that is well-respected is also hard to get into.

Comment: The new topic is not as competitive/established, so its top venues are easier to get in.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> For the last 6-8 month I made barely any progress (lots of failed
>   experiments)

This sounds like you have not treated your [prelims as a contract negotiation](http://matt.might.net/articles/advice-for-phd-thesis-proposals/).

The best advice I've received is that when you pitch your thesis topic to the committee, make sure that everyone agrees on the structure and methodologies involved. That way, if your work falters or your experiments fail, but you followed the guidance outlined by your committee, then you have still earned a pass.

Another piece of great advice is this: [nobody is going to read your thesis](https://www.insidehighered.com/advice/2011/09/12/essay_on_the_role_of_dissertations_in_an_academic_job_search).

Do not switch your program and do not start over, just complete the tasks you were given and move on. If you decide to switch fields later on, fine... that's normal, reasonable, and expected.

And just because you're studying one thing in school doesn't mean that's what you have to do for the rest of your life. There have been plenty of PhDs that completely jumped fields of study, out of CS and into sociology for example... or vice versa. Besides, the latest rage these days is adding "multi-disciplinary" to your grant proposals.

Comment: This is frankly horrible advice, particularly if there is a publication requirement for graduation. If the experiments fail or the work falters, there are no publications, and you can't "earn a pass." Moreover, sometimes there isn't a "pitch to the thesis committee" until close to graduation. So there might be plenty of time for things to go south before the thesis committee gets involved.

Comment: @aeismail Like it or not, the fact is that a publication requirement for program completion is more of the exception than the norm. And if you're pitching your thesis right before graduation, that's in poor taste.

Comment: @Alexandros there are multiple ways to get a PhD in CS, and CS isn't a unique or magical program in academia. I've seen all engineering programs - not just  CS - require either a dissertation bundled from multiple publications or a single body of work. It usually boils down to whats easiest for the student and the committee agrees on.

Comment: @Alexandros My program didn't require it. I just looked at Stanford's and didn't see a requirement. Are you talking about a conference paper? I haven't read of a requirement for a conference paper, but I know that conference papers are more common in CS programs. Regardless, conference paper != a peer reviewed journal publication.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24387/discussion-between-twitch-and-alexandros).

Comment: I've added links to support my advice and will also include another Academia discussion about the value of conference papers as publications. You can make up your own mind, but my understanding from looking at several top ranked program requirements is that (1) publications are not a universal requirement and (2) conference papers do not carry the same weight or prestige as a journal article. http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18349/difference-between-conference-paper-and-journal-paper

Comment: I think this *may* be valid advice if the OP has no interest to stay in academia. If (s)he wants to, then finishing a bad thesis is career suicide while nobody cares if you spent more time on your thesis.

Comment: @xLeitix Since I'm not interested in a faculty position, that's the perspective I tend to hold, but more than once and by academics on all levels, when I've asked the question (I was quite nervous about this my first year), they've all said nobody cares about the dissertation beyond that it was completed. That advice is echoed in the link I provided above for "nobody is going to read your thesis". Since I haven't been on the faculty hiring side... I can't say this is a universal truth, but I've also never been told "your thesis will affect your ability to be hired".

Comment: @Twitch I think that's true in the most literal sense (most people don't care about the *thesis text* per se), but very wrong in a practical sense (the papers you wrote as part of your thesis are by and far the most important part of any postdoc or faculty application).

Comment: @xLeitix Is there any other source of information that you could provide that says the thesis is critical? Aside from that link, here's advice from a UCSB CS faculty member that says it isn't important: http://bit.ly/1FsbHSr ... and this one from a USC faculty member: http://bit.ly/1ALOOfM

Comment: @Twitch I only checked the first link, but it says exactly what I said. The thesis is *not* important per se, but publications done as part of your thesis work are. However, if you "barely make any progress" with "lots of failed experiments", where would these great publications come from?

Comment: @xLeitix OP stated s/he could produce publications. There is no reason they have to be great, just enough to get the PhD and move on. I think the OP can always look for a post-doc fellowship and pursue better publications if seeking a faculty position.

Comment: Sadly the process in my country does not necessarily involve a formal proposal (the one for the new topic would involve something similar) and no committee – my PhD is pretty much given at my advisors whim.

Answer (score 3):

**Most people won't care.**

The time to PhD isn't really considered all that important unless it's *highly* anomalous (much shorter or longer than standard), and if you get good publications out of it, nobody is going to make a big deal about switching topics. It happens for all kinds of reasons—funding changes, or because the original project doesn't pan out for whatever reason (technical or logistical).

It will also not impact your career much, unless you're planning to continue studying one of those areas as your post-graduation career. Again, the overall quality tends to matter much more than the actual topic in most cases (particularly if you're moving into a different area from your graduate work).

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Any idea if this is also true for industry careers?

Comment: Again, I think it's not important, unless you're being trained in a topic the particular business you're applying to is interested in.